# How do convert date to Unix timestamp in milliseconds

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset with a column that represents date time the following format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`

I want to convert this date-time in a Unix timestamp at millisecond granularity. 
I tried the following:

`filteredDS.withColumn(TIMESTAMP, unix_timestamp(filteredDS(TIMESTAMP)))`

but this just gives me the timestamp in seconds and not milliseconds. 
How do I get the timestamp in millis from a date column?